# Why would you risk bankruptcy if you lend more money than you own?

Tags: financial-literacy, bankruptcy, lending

Difficult to summarize the question in just a few words, so let me elaborate here. I am currently reading the *Financial Times Guide to Banking* by Glen Arnold, section *Money creation*, and there is something I cannot wrap my head around. The section of the book is explaining how goldsmiths were effectively acting as primitive banks in storing gold deposits once upon a time, and giving paper money in return:

> The borrowers of the money from goldsmiths were usually content to take a piece of paper - call it a **bank note** - instead of taking coins out of the bank. They could then use that as currency to buy things. The goldsmiths could just create these pieces of paper off their own bat. Thus, a goldsmith bank might have a total of, say, £1,000 deposited, but hand out £500 of the coin as loans and issue another £5,000 or £6,000 or new paper money to borrowers.
>
> [...]
>
> [...] if you are working off a deposit base of £1,000 and you lend £4,000, and then 30% of your borrowers are unable to pay, you are bankrupt.

*Why* would you be bankrupt? If you are creating money that does not exist (in this case, money that you don't physically have since it is not backed up by actual gold), and someone does not pay you back, what would you be losing exactly, since you did not spend anything in the first place?

Assuming that you have £1,000, that you lend out £4,000, and that 30% of this (£1,200) is lost, would you not still get back the other £2,800 from the other loans, thus making you richer anyway?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A bank note given out by a goldsmith in that time was not just fiat money. It was actually a voucher which came with the guarantee that if it was given back to the goldsmith, that goldsmith would be obligated to give that amount of gold to the current owner of the bank note. That's why people considered those bank notes as if they were gold. Because they were assured that as long as they owned the bank note, they could exchange it back for gold at the goldsmith.

However, that would become a problem if a lot of people had that idea at once, went to the goldsmith, and they didn't have that much gold available. Now the goldsmith was indebted to all those people with bank notes.

Now to get back to the example the question is talking about.

In that case the goldsmith did not receive gold in exchange for those bank notes, they merely lent the bank notes in exchange for the debtor being indebted to them. The debtor was now obligated to either pay back in gold or in bank notes.

But then the debtor lost those bank notes and does not have gold either. So they can't pay back. At first, this seems like a zero sum game for the goldsmith. They gave out banknotes not backed by anything and they won't get any of the gold or notes they expected. But don't forget that those bank notes are not gone! They are now in circulation, owned by someone else. That someone else now has the right to go to the goldsmith and demand their gold. "But those were just a loan" isn't an answer the new owner of those bank notes has to accept.

Comment: "But don't forget that those bank notes are not gone! They are now in circulation, owned by someone else. That someone else now has the right to go to the goldsmith and demand their gold."

I think this is the part I was missing: I mistakenly assumed that the obligation to pay would be the debtor's, rather than the goldsmith's (in your example, the someone else should have ultimately demanded the money from the debtor, not from the goldsmith).

Comment: @user1301428 The insolvent debtor of the goldsmith does not necessarily have creditors. It is very well possible (in fact likely) that they lost all that money through bad business decisions.

Comment: This is why it's important to understand that a run on a bank can't bankrupt a bank. It can, however, reveal that the bank was already bankrupt -- typically due to making too many loans that are not repaid.

Comment: British money still carries the inscription _"I promise to pay the bearer on demand the sum of five/ten/twenty/fifty pounds"_.

Comment: @Llama indeed - and apparently the Bank of England did indeed used to give the bearer gold in exchange for a banknote. Nowadays, however, they will simply exchange it for another banknote! ([source](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/freedom-of-information/2016/25-february-2016)).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That isn't right; a bank can easily have more bank notes outstanding than it currently has in reserves.  Given time, it can call in its loans in order to pay off its obligations (circulating banknotes it issued).  Banking converts a long-repayment obligation (the loans it makes) into short-repayment obligations (banknotes) based off the statistical defence of "nobody is going to come in with every banknote at once".  A run is when that fails.  Banks can defend with a delay and being able to borrow from other banks, except when a credit crunch makes that impossible, then boom.

Comment: Go watch "It's a Wonderful Life", the scene where Jimmy Stewart is trying to stop the run on his Savings and Loan, and he explains why he can't satisfy everyone because he took their deposits and loaned them to their neighbors.

Comment: @Yakk There's no "boom". So long as the bank is solvent, it can repay every debt it owes and it can even fully compensate anyone whose payment is delayed. Depositors may be inconvenienced, but that's the risk they take in exchange for the interest they receive.

Comment: @Barmar So long as he remains solvent and was adequately capitalized, he can eventually repay everyone with sufficient interest to fully compensate them. A run on a bank can't make it insolvent unless it wasn't properly capitalized to begin with. (In the old days, banks explicitly had a provision that set the interest customers got in such emergency situations where the bank had a liquidity crunch so this would not be a surprise. It was enough to incentivize the bank to avoid such problems if humanly possible and banks had the capital to cover if needed.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz He wasn't well capitalized, he was operating hand to mouth. Then his absent-minded uncle misplaced a deposit, so he was under water when the run occurred. This was before the Great Depression, and the creation of banking regulations that required significant capital reserves.

Comment: @Barmar Gotcha. A run on a bank can reveal that it has insufficient capital reserves. If it has sufficient capital reserves and its loans aren't bad, then there's no problem. It can fully compensate everyone for all their losses as it agreed to do when it took the deposits. (Of course, that an unscrupulous bank can become and remain insolvent, typically due to making risky loans, for some time and continue taking deposits is its own problem.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If you have 100 million dollars in "withdraw any time" accounts, it needs 100 million dollars in capital reserves to avoid any possible run from making the bank unable to fulfill its credit obligations (aka insolvent). If it can defer the withdrawals, then capital reserves don't matter; it can just say "naw, I'll pay you back when my loans mature". I mean, you can write into all of your account agreements "I don't have to actually pay you this money on demand, I can instead give you some extra interest and pay you later". That isn't really what people think of as a bank account.

Comment: @Yakk That's precisely what banks did before insurance was widespread. They included specific (and incredibly generous) interest terms in the event the bank encountered a liquidity crisis and ensured they had sufficient capitalization to honor those terms should they encounter a run. This is how banks were operated (at least, those operated by non-crooks) before insurance and a run would, at worst, create a short-term liquidity problem for customers. Generally, it wouldn't even do that because the bank across the street would buy the future payments. It's a solved problem.

Comment: @Barmar I think that may have been an anachronism in the movie then, because when Clarence is being shown the events of George Bailey's life *before* the run on the bank, he learns that George wept on both VE day *and* VJ day, which meant that the run had to have occurred *after* World War II and thus well after the Great Depression and the creation of said banking regulations.

Comment: @Andy The run on the bank happened in the flashback to the Great Depression. You're confusing the run on the bank with when Uncle Billy misplaced the bank deposit in the present (Xmas Eve, 1945).

Comment: @Barmar Oh wow you're right... the bank run was right before George was supposed to go on his honeymoon.